# Leveled up too quickly in Skyrim; Enemies now too difficult

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I spent a lot of time exploring and doing side missions, and not really leveling my smithing or my enchanting, and now I'm a really high level. Almost any enemy can kill me and none of the items that are spawning are good enough to help.

Is there any way to restore the balance in my game or do I have to start over?

Comment: Are you playing on PC?

Comment: What difficulty are you playing on?

Comment: @ZeroStack whether OP is playing on PC or not doesn't matter - SE is about answers that help everybody with a particular problem, that's why we close duplicate questions.

Comment: @kotekzot I think it does matter as he can use console commands to spawn better gear or manually change his stats. (where you cannot do this on console)

Comment: The game usually isn't so hard that you would *need* to powerlevel your blacksmithing.  Unless he's just done nothing but level speech and pickpocketing, we should be able to have a reasonable playstyle or three that would fit whatever levels/perks he's already got.

Comment: Yeah I'm on console

Comment: @user88319 What skills have the highest level for you?  Can you give us a top 4 or 5 skills where your character is strongest?

Comment: @ZeroStack whether OP can do it or not is irrelevant, other people with the same problem will be playing on PC and will benefit from an answer containing PC-only solutions.

Comment: My character is pretty levelled all around I think I just need to smith/improve/buy some better weapons

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can still save your character if you invest a lot of time in leveling blacksmithing ect. You will need a lot of cash. Sell all your items that you have hoarded over time. One big problem might be the perks, as you might have spent all of them on other stuff.

Here is what you need to do:

- Level up alchemy

  - [What is the fastest way to level up my alchemy skill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-level-up-my-alchemy-skill)
- Level up blacksmithing

  - [What is an effective way to level smithing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/what-is-an-effective-way-to-level-smithing)
- Level up enchanting

  - [What is the fastest way to level up my alchemy skill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-level-up-my-alchemy-skill)

Drink or sell your potions to merchants. Enchant your weapons or jewelry and sell them back to merchants. At first this is a big money dump, but later you will actually profit form the transactions.

You can combine the leveling with [training](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35324/how-often-can-i-pay-to-train-skills). Train and steal back your money. Later you can paralyze the trainers to pickpocket it out of them while they cannot move.

If you run out of ingredients you can wait or fast travel between the big cities and buy all the stock from alchemists (ingredients), blacksmiths (ingots and leather) and enchanters (gem stone).

Do not fight. Run away from any monsters that might kill you. For enchanting get only souls from monsters that you are able to kill (e.g. crabs around Whiterun).

Be aware that this is really boring and time consuming. The best way to do these tasks (in a new game) is during other missions. Whenever you return to a big city, buy all ingredients etc. and craft materials that you sell instantly to merchants or stash in your house.